# Cordova include script with relative double slash url

Tags: javascript, cordova, src

I have to include javascript code for etracker in a Cordova App, it is loading an external js file with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//path.js"></script>
```

Because of the Cordova platform the url is building with `file://` instead of `http://`
If I make a string replace in `src="//path.js"` to `src="http://path.js"` it works, but all dependencies in `path.js` going to `file://` again.
Is there any solution to work with relative double slash urls in Cordova?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Hi swanhella, no I guess there is no solution, you cant use double slash urls in cordova